# how to increase the range of KY-005?

Tags: arduino-uno, remote-control, infrared

I am using a KY-005 with an Arduino Uno. I have the knowledge that Arduino can provide a forward current of 40 mA. How can I make it to 55 mA or above upto 60 mA to unlock its full potential, so as to get efficient IR communication without data being distorted at the KY-022 IR receiver?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think 40 mA to output from a GPIO is not a wise idea, because those are [Arduino Pin Current Limitations](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/ArduinoPinCurrentLimitations).

What you can do is:

- The VCC pin can handle 200 mA. So you can use this pin to power your KY-005 and use a transistor to switch it via a GPIO (much less than 40 mA is needed for that).
- Or (high likely not needed): use an external power source and use a transistor in the same way.

For knowing all details about using a transistor this way, google for "transistor as switch".